# Can I mimic multiple passed-object dummy arguments in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

I would like to write a procedure which takes two passed-object dummy arguments, such as

```
module m
  type, abstract :: Parent
  contains
    procedure(f_Parent), deferred :: f
  end type

  abstract interface
    subroutine f_Parent(foo,bar)
      import Parent
      implicit none
      class(Parent), intent(in) :: foo
      class(Parent), intent(in) :: bar
    end subroutine
  end interface

  type, extends(Parent) :: Child
  contains
    procedure, public :: f => f_Child
  end type
contains
  subroutine f_Child(foo,bar)
    implicit none
    class(Child), intent(in) :: foo
    class(Child), intent(in) :: bar
  end subroutine
end module
```

but this is not allowed by the Fortran standard, as `bar` is not a passed-object dummy argument, and so must be `class(Parent)` and not `class(Child)`.

My current solution is

```
subroutine f_Child(foo,bar)
  implicit none
  class(Child),  intent(in) :: foo
  class(Parent), intent(in) :: bar

  select type(bar); type is(Child) 
  end select
end subroutine
```

which works, but the `select type` construct is too slow, and dominates the runtime of my code (this subroutine is called many times).

I have tried having a single passed-object argument which holds both `foo` and `bar`, e.g. as an array or pointer, but this is also forbidden by the standard.

Is there any way of mimicking the behaviour of having multiple passed-object dummy arguments which does not incur the cost of a `select type` construct? Or maybe a faster way of getting an argument of `class(Child)` from `class(Parent)`?

Comment: In general, performance and OOP go perpendicular to each other. So, as a general rule of thumb, you should avoid OOP in performance-critical sections of your code. This is not unique to Fortran and applies to any language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using single dispatch twice:

```
Module m

  Implicit None

  Type, Public, Abstract :: Parent
   Contains
     Procedure( i_Parent_Parent ),              Public , Deferred :: f
     Procedure( i_Child_Parent  ), Pass( bar ), Private, Deferred :: f_c_p
     Procedure( i_set           ),              Public , Deferred :: set
  End Type Parent

  Type, Public, Extends( Parent ) :: Child
     Integer               , Private :: data
   Contains
     Procedure             , Public  :: f     => f_Child_Parent
     Procedure, Pass( bar ), Private :: f_c_p => f_Child_Child
     Procedure             , Public  :: set   => f_Child_set
  End Type Child

  Private

  Abstract Interface
     Subroutine i_Parent_Parent( foo, bar )
       Import :: Parent
       Implicit None
       Class( Parent ), Intent( In ) :: foo
       Class( Parent ), Intent( In ) :: bar
     End Subroutine i_Parent_Parent
     Subroutine i_Child_Parent( foo, bar )
       Import :: Parent, Child
       Implicit None
       Class( Child  ), Intent( In ) :: foo
       Class( Parent ), Intent( In ) :: bar
     End Subroutine i_Child_Parent
     Subroutine i_set( foo, data )
       Import :: Parent
       Class( Parent ), Intent( InOut ) :: foo
       Integer        , Intent( In    ) :: data
     End Subroutine i_set
  End Interface

Contains

  Subroutine f_Child_Parent( foo, bar )
    Implicit None
    Class( Child  ), Intent( In ) :: foo
    Class( Parent ), Intent( In ) :: bar
    Call bar%f_c_p( foo )
  End Subroutine f_Child_Parent

  Subroutine f_Child_Child( foo, bar )
    Implicit None
    Class( Child ), Intent( In ) :: foo
    Class( Child ), Intent( In ) :: bar
    Write( *, * ) 'In child child foo%data = ', foo%data, ' bar%data = ', bar%data
  End Subroutine f_Child_Child

  Subroutine f_Child_set( foo, data )
    Implicit None
    Class( Child ), Intent( InOut ) :: foo
    Integer       , Intent( In    ) :: data
    foo%data = data
  End Subroutine f_Child_set

End Module m

Program driver

  Use m, Only : Parent, Child

  Class( Parent ), Allocatable :: foo, bar

  Allocate( Child :: foo )
  Allocate( Child :: bar )

  Call foo%set( 3 )
  Call bar%set( 4 )

  Call foo%f( bar )

End Program driver
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-8 -std=f2008  -fcheck=all -Wall -Wextra dd.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 In child child foo%data =            3  bar%data =            4
ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```

Whether this is quicker than `select type` will be implementation dependent, but I think it is cleaner.

Comment: This nicely answers the question asked, thank you, but unfortunately doesn't work in my case. If I make the Parent module dependent on the various Child modules then I have circular dependencies.

Comment: Well see if you can come up with a new question (don't edit this one) which is closer to what you need and then people here can have a think about that