# Can I mimic multiple passed-object dummy arguments without adding dependencies?

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

I previously asked [Can I mimic multiple passed-object dummy arguments in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168375/can-i-mimic-multiple-passed-object-dummy-arguments-in-fortran)

I over-simplified my problem for that question, and a better example of the code I would like to write is

```
module m_Parent
  type, abstract :: Parent
  contains
    procedure(f_Parent), deferred :: f
  end type

  abstract interface
    subroutine f_Parent(foo,bar)
      import Parent
      implicit none
      class(Parent), intent(in) :: foo
      class(Parent), intent(in) :: bar
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

module m_Child
  use m_Parent

  type, extends(Parent) :: Child
  contains
    procedure, public :: f => f_Child
  end type
contains
  subroutine f_Child(foo,bar)
    implicit none
    class(Child), intent(in) :: foo
    class(Child), intent(in) :: bar
  end subroutine
end module
```

with the constraint that `m_Parent` may not have dependencies on `m_Child`, to avoid circular dependencies and to allow for many `Child` classes without having to update `m_Parent` with the details of each.

As before:

- the code presented here is forbidden by the Fortran standard.
- the `select type` construct is too slow.

Can I mimic the behaviour that the above code would produce if multiple passed-object dummy arguments were allowed by the Fortran standard?

Comment: *the select type construct is too slow*. Really ?  I'd be interested to see some figures on that.  I'll admit that my own experience of using `select type` is confined to no more than a few 000 'objects' in flight at any time and hadn't noticed that `select type` is a bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, according to operf the implementation with `select type` has that one line taking more than 10% of my entire runtime.

Comment: Only 10%? How much improvement in speed do you need? From the figures you have given you are not going to get a huge improvement without a large rethink. Also Have you tried other versions of your compiler, or other compilers?

Comment: Sure, 10% is not a lot, but it is seems like a very unnecessary 10%.

Comment: @veryreverie You should take into account that the programme will need to be able to determine the dynamic type at run time and this is always going to involve some overhead. You will not be able to save all 10%. In fact, how would you tell that the 10% is slow? Perhaps it is fast, actually. If you get this working for your use case, please, report back with how much speedup you achieved. It would be useful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard forbids multiple passed-object dummy arguments, along with passed-object dummy arguments which are arrays or pointers. The standard does not forbid passed-object dummy arguments which are classes containing arrays or pointers.

This can be implemented as

```
module m_Parent
  type, abstract :: Parent
  end type

  type, abstract :: ParentPair
  contains
    procedure(f_ParentPair), deferred :: f
  end type

  abstract interface
    subroutine f_ParentPair(foobar)
      import ParentPair
      implicit none
      class(ParentPair), intent(in) :: foobar
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

module m_Child
  use m_Parent

  type, extends(Parent) :: Child
  contains
    procedure, public :: f => f_Child
  end type

  type, extends(ParentPair) :: ChildPair
    type(Child) :: foo
    type(Child) :: bar
  contains
    procedure, public :: f => f_ChildPair
  end type

contains

  subroutine f_ChildPair(foobar)
    implicit none
    class(ChildPair), intent(in) :: foobar
    call foobar%foo%f(foobar%bar)
  end subroutine

  subroutine f_Child(foo,bar)
    implicit none
    class(Child), intent(in) :: foo
    class(Child), intent(in) :: bar
  end subroutine
end module
```

This is not the most elegant solution, and it requires the creation and maintenance of an entire `ChildPair` class for every implementation of `Child`.

According to operf, in ifort 19.1 this has a negligible overhead compared to a `select type` statement.

Comment: I won't accept this answer for a while, to see if anyone can come up with a solution which requires less coding overhead.