Fortran class select type with multiple arguments
I want to write a subroutine taking as argument two class objects which can be of any extended type from a common ancestor. Inside the subroutine I will have a type select to check the class. Since I know that the two objects will be of the same type, is it possible to avoid check the type of both? The following is a minimal example of what I would like to achieve (which at the moment is wrong):
program main

    implicit none

    type :: base
    end type base

    type, extends(base) :: ext1
        integer :: i
    end type ext1

    type, extends(base) :: ext2
        integer :: j
    end type ext2

    type(ext1) :: a, b
    type(ext2) :: c, d

    call my_subroutine(c, d)

contains

    subroutine my_subroutine(obj1, obj2)

        class(base), intent(in) :: obj1, obj2

        select type(obj1)
            type is (ext1)
                print *, obj1%i + obj2%i
            type is (ext2)
                print *, obj1%j + obj2%j
        end select
    end subroutine my_subroutine
end program

I cannot access obj2%i or obj2%j since the type of obj2 has never been checked.
foo2.f08:29:40:

   29 |                 print *, obj1%i + obj2%i
      |                                        1
Error: ‘i’ at (1) is not a member of the ‘base’ structure
foo2.f08:31:40:

   31 |                 print *, obj1%j + obj2%j
      |                                        1
Error: ‘j’ at (1) is not a member of the ‘base’ structure

Is there a way to overcome this issue without explicitly checking the type of  obj2 ?

Please read this other question and its answers and see whether they help you understand why the answer is "no".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168375/can-i-mimic-multiple-passed-object-dummy-arguments-in-fortran/60187381#60187381 may be of use as well. personally I would avoid Select Type wherever possible

Thanks for the replies, I understand that it is no possible.
